# execSQL not working with insert

Tags: android, sqlite

i know that documentation says that it's better in this case to use insert instead of execSQL, but i have a very big sql-file that consist of 6000 records and it's easier for me to use execSQL, but it's not working

```
public class CitiesHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // All Static variables
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "cities";

    // Login table name
    private static final String TABLE_REGION= "region";
    private static final String TABLE_CITY= "city";
    // Login Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static final String KEY_REGION_ID = "region_id";
    private static final String KEY_PHONE = "phone_code";

    public CitiesHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String strRegion="CREATE TABLE region (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,name TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(strRegion);
        String insertRegion="INSERT INTO region Values   (1, 'АР Крым') , (2, 'Винницкая область') , (3, 'Волынская область') , (4, 'Днепропетровская область') , (5, 'Донецкая область') , (6, 'Житомирская область') , (7, 'Закарпатская область') , (8, 'Запорожская область') , (9, 'Ивано-Франковская область') , (10, 'Киевская область') , (11, 'Кировоградская область') , (12, 'Луганская область') , (13, 'Львовская область') , (14, 'Николаевская область') , (15, 'Одесская область') , (16, 'Полтавская область') , (17, 'Ровенская область') , (18, 'Сумская область') , (19, 'Тернопольская область') , (20, 'Харьковская область') , (21, 'Херсонская область') , (22, 'Хмельницкая область') , (23, 'Черкасская область') , (24, 'Черниговская область') , (25, 'Черновицкая область')";
        db.execSQL(insertRegion);
    }

    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CITY);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_REGION);
        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public String[] getRegions(){
        HashMap<String,String> user = new HashMap<String,String>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_REGION;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        // Move to first row
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
            user.put("name", cursor.getString(1));
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        String [] regions;
        regions=new String[user.values().size()];
        for (Entry<String, String> entry : user.entrySet()) {
            int i=0;
            regions[i] = entry.getValue();      
            i++;
        }
        // return user
        return regions;
    }

    public int getRegionID(String name){
        HashMap<String,String> user = new HashMap<String,String>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_REGION+" WHERE name="+name;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        // Move to first row
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
            user.put("id", cursor.getString(0));
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        // return user
        return Integer.valueOf(user.get("id"));
    }

    public String[] getCities(int region_id){
        HashMap<String,String> user = new HashMap<String,String>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CITY+" WHERE region_id="+String.valueOf(region_id);

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        // Move to first row
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
            user.put("name", cursor.getString(1));
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        String [] cities;
        cities=new String[user.values().size()];
        for (Entry<String, String> entry : user.entrySet()) {
            int i=0;
            cities[i] = entry.getValue();       
            i++;
        }
        // return user
        return cities;
    }

}
```

thanks for any help

it's not working - it means everytime it's empty. insert statement is not fulfilled.

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: Feel free to explain what "it's not working" means.

Comment: Why not use the SQliteDatabase basic query methods... instead of using rawQuery since you aren't doing very complicated queries...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to insert multiple rows at a time in an SQLite database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609637/is-it-possible-to-insert-multiple-rows-at-a-time-in-an-sqlite-database)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always use execSQL between beginTransaction and EndTransaction, you tried?

Here is an excerpt of code:

```
String cmd = "QUERY FOR EXECUTE";
SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
db.beginTransaction();

if (cmd.trim().length() > 0) {
    db.execSQL(cmd);
}

db.setTransactionSuccessful();
db.endTransaction();
db.close();
```

Make sure you have write permissions too.

Comment: `onCreate()` is already inside a transaction.

Answer (score 3):

I would still use Android's provided `insert()`. It seems from your code that you are not passing arguments correctly to the `VALUES SQLite` command. See [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_insert_query.htm) for an `INSERT INTO` explanation.

Comment: Agree. Here's an [example using SQLite insert within DB transaction](http://android.codota.com/scenarios/528e1e21da0ae9404ad3ab53/android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase?tag=bumblebee)

Comment: i would do that but i have big sql-statement and don't want to parse it

Comment: It is not a statement that is that long. I do not know what you mean by parsing, but using the `insert()` is a better choice still.